# How do I divide in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb Z $?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I divide in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb Z $ ?

lets assume I'm in $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb Z $ so how do I calculate $\frac{17}{3}$ as an example?

The reason I'm asking is later it is becoming difficult when we calculate with polynomials in quotient rings

Comment: There is no such thing as division in general for these rings. Here the analogous operation is multiplying by the multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field for $p$ prime, every element has a multiplicative inverse. Hence $\frac{a}{b}=ab^{-1}$. In our case $3^{-1}=2$ since $3 \cdot 2= 6 =1$ and $\frac{17}{3}=17 \cdot 2= 34= 4$

Comment: what if we had $Z/4Z$ or in general with polynomials

Comment: If $n$ is not prime, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, so not every element has a multiplicative inverse  and there are also zero divisors (take for example $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$). What do you mean with polynomials?

Comment: so i cannot calcute it when my construct is not a field right ? i mean if i have something like $Z/2Z}[X] / (x+1) $ as an example

Comment: Every nonzero element in Z/pZ has an inverse. In general $a\in Z/nZ$ has a multiplicative inverse if and only if $gcd(a,n)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

To divide, you multiply by the inverse, which is known as soon as you have a Bézout's relation with $p$.

Her for instance, in, $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$, you have $17\equiv 2\mod 5$ and
$\;3\cdot 2-5=1$,hence $\;3^{-1}\equiv 2\mod 5$, so$$\frac{17}3\text{ denotes actually } \;2\cdot 2\equiv 4\equiv -1\mod 5.$$

Comment: what if my construct was not a field such as $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$

Comment: The denomi,ator should be coprime to the modulus to be invertible, and you still have a Bézout's relation. Other than that, you cannot always divide when you're not in a field.

Comment: so if my denominator is not invertible i cannot do that. $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$ if my denominator is 3 it is not possible ?

Comment: $3$ is its own inverse module $3$, so you ‘divide’ by $3$. However, I wouldnt use this vobulary, which is rather confusional with what happens in $\mathbf R$.

Comment: sorry i meant $2$

Comment: Oh! yes. In this ring the only multiples of $2$ are $0$ and $2$.

Comment: thanks for that did not know that, algebra becomes abstract one has to be precise such as with dividing in that ring and that it is not always possible

Answer (score 0):

Well, in any commutative ring $R$, the division is defined as
$$a:b = \frac{a}{b} = a\cdot b^{-1},$$
where $a,b\in R$ and $b$ is a unit (invertible) in $R$.

In your case, $17\equiv 2\mod 5$ and so $17/3 = 2/3$. Thus $2/3 = 2\cdot 3^{-1} = 2\cdot 2 = 4$.